# Implementing a constructor with two methods that prints all values inferior to zero in java

Tags: java, algorithm, terminal

I can't compile when I run the following program in the terminal. I would like to know is it so.

```
public class Testing {

    private static int TwiceRepetition(int[] elems) {

  ///
      return false;

    }   

    ///
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to compile?

Comment: The error messages from `javac` are **telling you** why the code cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing various closing "}" and type definition for variables :

```
public class Testing {

    private static int InfThanZero(int[] elems) {

        int i = 0;
        for (int element : elems) {
            if (element < 0) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (String s : args) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(s) < 0) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not needed for your example

Comment: just copy it and delete `package test;`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132640/discussion-between-ted-idzikowski-and-1blustone).